# Delete class instance in JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I have this class instance which is just a simple setup with a constructor with a few variables and a function named `DeleteMe`.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.foo = "bar";
  }

  DeleteMe() {
    // Code
  }
}
```

In the function `DeleteMe`, I would like to destroy/delete this class instance. How can achieve that? If I initiated a class and executed the method, I would like the class to always return `undefined` when accessed like so:

```js
const MyNewClass = new MyClass();   // Create a new class instance
console.log(MyNewClass.foo);        // > "bar"

MyNewClass.DeleteMe();              // Delete the instance of the class
console.log(MyNewClass.foo);        // > undefined
console.log(MyNewClass);            // > undefined

const MyOtherClass = new MyClass(); // I can initiate another just fine
console.log(MyOtherClass.foo);      // > "bar"
```

For clarification, I have a goal to reduce memory space (but if that would be possible, it would be great as well), I would just like to destroy this instance so you can't use it again.

What can I do to achieve this in `// Code` of the `DeleteMe` function?

Comment: Did you read about [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)?

Comment: I would like the class to delete itself or turn itself into an undefined and I'm not sure it's possible. Is it possible that, in the class function, I can use `delete this;`?

Comment: @Mehdi That would not help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var myobj = {};
myobj .instance = new Class();
//since 'myobj .instance' is your only reference to the object, whenever you wanted to destroy do this:
myobj.instance = null;
// OR
delete myobj.instance;
```

Comment: Is it possible that "the class deletes itself", as in, a function of the class makes it go, *poof*?

Comment: No. JavaScript is automatically garbage collected; the object's memory will be reclaimed only if the GC decides to run.